# Use images in Highcharts as xAxis labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to create a column chart in polar coordinate (wind rose) and I'd like to have images in place of the usual xAxis labels.

Can you help in correctly center the image?

```js
var img_path = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/navigation-set-arrows-part-two/32/Arrow_Right_Circle-48.png'


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'column'
    },
    
    xAxis:{
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {    
                return '<img src="' + img_path + '" />';
            },
            useHTML: true
        }
    },

    series:[{
        data: [{x:1, y:4}, {x:2, y:7}, {x:3, y:2}, {x:4, y:5}, {x:5, y:8}]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set width and height of the image.

```
 formatter: function() {                
   return '<img src="' + img_path + '" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" />';
 },
```

Also you can adjust aligning with:

```
align: 'center'
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/kz8h8uw9/

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. One last question. It seems to me that, unless I set width and height of the img to 30px, there will always be a small overlap with the axis line. I tried to play with margins and spacing but didn;t have luck. Any idea?

Comment: You can increase the distance option - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.distance - http://jsfiddle.net/kz8h8uw9/1/